# Custom function inside setInterval not working

Tags: node.js

I have a function that takes an array, performs some operations and returns a number. Here's a truncated version:

```
function similarity(phrases){
    if(phrases.length ==2){
    //Lots of stuff
    //concerning the phrases happen here
    // and a variable called similarity is produced which
    //contains a number
        return similarity;
    }else{
        throw "Can only find similarity between 2 phrases"; 
    }   
}
```

If I call this function separately it works perfectly. If, however I try to use it inside setInterval, it throws an error.

```
setInterval(function(){console.log(similarity(["test","test"]))},2000);
```

The expected outcome is "1.00000" every 2 seconds. Instead, "1.00000" is printed once and then this error is thrown:

> "setInterval(function(){console.log(similarity(["test","test"]))},2000);
>
> TypeError:String is not a function"

(pointing to the "s" on similarity).

Any ideas on what the problem is?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works fine in my env. Have you tried to run the truncated code and checked it works OK?

Comment: Just tried running the truncated/dummy version. Same problem.
http://pastebin.com/KueCTB1f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're saving function result in variable called same way as function (`similarity`). This way you are overriding function from upper scope.
Try this:

```
function similarity(phrases) {
    var similarity;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. I instead changed the name though and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In future try use some JS Lint tools to see, if there is no easy to catch problems :)